# Rails Site Maintenance/Monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maintenance

I am setting up a daily maintenance task for my rails app. When the task is complete is sends me an e-mail that summarizes the tasks activity. If you were doing the same, what kind of tasks would your run? What kind of information would like that e-mail to contain?

Some examples might be:

Rotate/Truncate the site logs Summary of user activity (very app specific obviously)

Any other things that you guys might suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other thing we do with our Rails apps on a daily basis is clean up old sessions. But if you don't use ActiveRecord::SessionStore or similar, that's not needed.